# Q objects in django queryset

Tags: django, django-q

```
g = Goal.objects.filter(Q(title__contains=term) | Q(desc__contains=term))
```

How can I add to my `filter` that `user=request.user`?

This doesn't work:

```
g = Goal.objects.filter(user=request.user, Q(title__contains=term) | Q(desc__contains=term))
```

Models:

```
class Goal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    desc = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Please show your models first.

Comment: Don't just say, "this doesn't work", please include the traceback. In this case, the traceback is `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`, which explains exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keyword arguments (`user=request.user`) must come **after** non keyword arguments (your Q object).

Either switch the order in your filter:

```
Goal.objects.filter(Q(title__contains=term) | Q(desc__contains=term), user=request.user)
```

or chain two `filter()` calls together

```
Goal.objects.filter(user=request.user).filter(Q(title__contains=term) | Q(desc__contains=term))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
g = Goal.objects.filter(Q(user__iexact=request.user) & Q(title__contains=term) | Q(desc__contains=term))
```

Use & in place of Python and operator

Answer (score 1):

According to django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/).

Lookup functions can mix the use of Q objects and keyword arguments. However, if a Q object is provided, it must precede the definition of any keyword arguments.